# Extract to values with one regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i already have a Regex that do what i need:

```js
var text  = 'BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00 13 5 10.517,81 0,00 10.517,81 0,00 TOTAIS: 700 1.677.289,00 18.512,98 1.691.104,49 2.647,38';
var reg   = RegExp('(?:.*BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC)+' +
                '(?:.*?\\s+01(?:\\s+\\S+){3}\\s+(\\S+))?' + 
                '(?:.*?\\s+07(?:\\s+\\S+){3}\\s+(\\S+))?');

var match = reg.exec(text);

console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
```

The script will find the 01 and will push the value after 3 expressions, than will find the 07 and do the same, push the value after 3 expressions.

I need power up my Regex, say that i want push the value only after 3 numbers that could be commas or dots.

So i did this new regex:

```js
var text  = 'BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00 13 5 10.517,81 0,00 10.517,81 0,00 TOTAIS: 700 1.677.289,00 18.512,98 1.691.104,49 2.647,38';
var reg   = RegExp('(?:.*BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC)+' +
                '(?:.*?\\s+01(?:\\s[0-9\\,.]*){3}\\s+([0-9\\.,]*))?' +
                '(?:.*?\\s+01(?:\\s[0-9\\,.]*){3}\\s+([0-9\\.,]*))?');

var match = reg.exec(text);

console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
```

The problem is that the match[2] is undefined, but show not be. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide what should be your matching strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the 3rd line in your regex looks for a second "`01`". The var `text` only has one, and not a second ocurrence. Hence, the `match[2]`, which is inside an optional construct, does not match.

Just change the 2nd `\\s+01` to `\\s+07`.

---

**Corrected code:**

```js
var text  = 'BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00 13 5 10.517,81 0,00 10.517,81 0,00 TOTAIS: 700 1.677.289,00 18.512,98 1.691.104,49 2.647,38';
var reg   = RegExp('(?:.*BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC)+' +
                '(?:.*?\\s+01(?:\\s[0-9\\,.]*){3}\\s+([0-9\\.,]*))?' +
                '(?:.*?\\s+07(?:\\s[0-9\\,.]*){3}\\s+([0-9\\.,]*))?');

var match = reg.exec(text);

console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
```